# Netlogo- average link length code snippet

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to monitor the length of my links in Netlogo- but I'm having a hard time getting used to the syntax. Is anyone familiar enough with it to just take the mean of all link-lengths?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this simple setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  ask turtles [
    if not any? my-links [
      create-link-with one-of other turtles
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

You can use `of` with `[link-length]` to return a list of link lengths (try just typing `print [link-length] of links` in the console), then use `mean` to take the mean of that list. If you put that in a `to-report` procedure, you will be able to display the `mean-link-length` in a "monitor" widget in the "Interface":

```
to-report mean-link-length
  report mean [link-length] of links
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works wonderfully! Embarrassingly, I was using 'of' in the incorrect syntax.

Comment: @L.P. - Not embarrassing! The syntax is not always obvious. Cheers.